# What is "/usr/local/bin/gc" and why is it throwing an error when I upgrade graphcool client?

Tags: node.js, npm, graphcool

`npm update -g graphcool`

I'm upgrading from v 0.5 to the latest graphcool client and I'm getting the following error

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/gc
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/gc: is outside /usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphcool and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/gc
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

What is /usr/local/bin/gc and should I delete it like it's asking for?

Comment: _What is_ - have you tried looking at the man page? [`man gc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gc)

Comment: "gc is a graph analogue to wc in that it prints to standard output the number of nodes, edges, connected components or clusters contained in the input files. It also prints a total count for all graphs if more than one graph is given."

Comment: that's the description - but I don't know if it should be deleted or not - or whether it was installed by graphcool or it's shared... Or why graphcool is trying to delete it